# extracting the index of a certain character in a cell array

Tags: matlab, if-statement, cells

I have a cell array like this:
[image]

and I want to extract the index of 2 in this cell array so I used these lines of codes:

```
for i = 1:size(idx,1)  
    if idx{i,1} ~= []  
       index = i;  
    end  
end
```

but the code doesn't work.I mean the debuger never enters if beacause it doesn't understand that 2 differs from [].why? and how do you suggest me to write the code?
note that the character will not always be 2 and it may occur in other indexes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Matlab, [] means empty, thus:

```
for i = 1:size(idx,1)  
   if ~isempty(idx{i,1})
      index = i;  
   end  
end
```

Answer (score 3):

To test if you variable is empty use [ISEMPTY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) function.

To do it for all elements in a cell array you can use [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
index = find(~cellfun(@isempty, idx));
```